# Unable to create Lakehouse in Microsoft Fabric

Tags: microsoft-fabric

following the documentation provided I created net new office account and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/get-started/fabric-trial I started Microsoft Fabric trial and created a workspace. However when I try creating a Lakehouse I'm getting error message "To create a Lakehouse, you need a free Microsoft Fabric trial capacity. Unfortunately, your Microsoft tenant has reached the maximum number of available free trial capacities" Can anyone please help on this.

Thanks in advance.

[error message box I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Rxm.png)

I'm trying to learn and explore Microsoft-fabric.

Comment: is this your own account? or part of an org?

Comment: this is my own personal account.

Comment: is it @gmail.com or something like that? or linked to a domain? you may have to try this
https://blog.fabric.microsoft.com/en-US/blog/accessing-microsoft-fabric-for-developers-startups-and-enterprises/